# What is meant by System Memory in android?

Tags: ram, storage

I have an LG -E405 phone running Android 2.3.6.

As can be seen [here](http://www.gsmarena.com/lg_optimus_l3_e405-4835.php), the phone has 1GB internal memory and 384Mb RAM.

When I look at default `App manager`, this is what I get,

- RAM - 231Mb
- System Memory - 157 Mb.
- Internal Memory - 378Mb.
- SD Card - 2Gb.

Also, all the applications I install, by default take up space from `System memory`.

Many tutorials explain about moving apps from internal memory to SD Card to free up space.

But, in my phone I only get the option to move from System Memory to Internal Memory.

It is like a whole new layer has been added in the memory heirarchy.

So, what is this `System Memory`.

Comment: Thanks to the details you've given: Looks like it's just confusing "display names". "System memory" seems to stand for "internal/phone memory", "Internal memory" means some "internal sd card". Sizes given obviously stand for "free/available space".